# Non Root User Helm & AKS

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I'm attempting to connect and run a pod in an AKS cluster (v1.19.6) as a non-root user with Helm (v3.5.2), and getting a crashback loop with the error `I have no name!`.  The docker image and service runs locally without an issue as the correct user at runtime.

After `helm create mychart` I set up my security in the values.yaml as :

```
podSecurityContext:
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 123
  

securityContext:
  # capabilities:
  #   drop:
  #   - ALL
  #readOnlyRootFilesystem: false
  runAsNonRoot: true
  runAsUser: 123
```

The deployment.yaml is below.  I've not modified anything else other than the parameters to connect to my AKS cluster:

```
spec:
  {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
  imagePullSecrets:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
  {{- end }}
  serviceAccountName: {{ include "mychart.serviceAccountName" . }}
  securityContext:
    {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
  containers:
    - name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
      image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
      imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
```

My Dockerfile ends with

```
USER 123

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "./blah; bash"]
```

Am I correct that this is most likely the issue? How do I go about resolving the problem?  Supporting documentation would be very helpful everything I'm finding is outdated.

Comment: Could you please show the full logs of that Pod? Also, a `kubectl describe pod` would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I created a startup script to start the service with the user declared.  Not sure if this is the K8s methodology but it worked. Will leave it unanswered in the event someone has a better solution.